# can i copy ruby distribution from utopic to vivid?

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I am shifting to vivid from utopic.
I have a working ruby environment installed with rvm of size around 1.7 GB.

Is there a way i can use this(or some part of it) in my newly installed vivid?

For example in R I had to just copy the packages folder and only installation needed was R-base-core

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install all the Ruby packages from the Vivid repository, and then copy your software / environment over, providing it can handle the version of Ruby in the repositories.

Copying over everything directly will potentially break things; the packages for Ruby are dependent on the version of Ruby in that repository, so an upgrade of the distribution requires you to also upgrade the Ruby to what's in that distro, and then move your environment over to see if it works.  (If it doesn't, then you redo your Ruby environment to update it to the codebase of Ruby you're on)